# I want to ask a question about Python virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

What happens when you activate a virtual environment named Foldenv in the terminal of python vscode and then use a virtual environment named venv in the palette?

[image]

i enter print ("hello world") in venv interpreter but terminal show me (Foldenv) in front of hello world

Comment: kill the terminal, when you run your Python script a terminal will be opened and the `venv` environment will be activated

Comment: If an interpreter named venv and a terminal running a virtual environment named Foldenv are prepared, if I execute "hello world", is it normal that the output is displayed in the virtual environment named Foldenv?

Comment: VSC does not know which virt env is active, if there is a terminal it uses the terminal as is, if no terminal active it creates one and activates the selected virt env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will use the python interpreter in the lower right corner (the one you selected in the Select Interpreter panel) to run the code.

But it doesn't activate another virtual environment again when there is already a terminal and activate a virtual environment. Unless you close the current terminal and run the code.

[image]

Another thing to note is that when you use the button to execute code in a terminal, then this terminal will always exist as the terminal for executing code. The following two cases are examples for your understanding.

#### The first case

Select the **Foldenv** environment interpreter and activate the environment in the terminal. Note that no code is running at this time.

[image]

Switch the interpreter to **.venv** in the ***Select Interpreter*** panel,
Use the play button to execute the code. At this time, a new terminal will be created automatically and the **.venv** environment will be activated to run the code.

[image]

#### The second case

Select the **Foldenv** environment interpreter and execute the code directly. A terminal is automatically created and the environment is activated at this point.

[image]

Switch the interpreter to **.venv** and run the code again. At this time, the code will be executed directly in the current terminal, but the **.venv** environment interpreter will be used.

[image]